# EXEC in SELECT statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Stored Procedure that gets some inputs and returns output (was converted from a function)
Also, I have a `SELECT` statement that retrieves data from multiple tables and used to call that function.
I just want to execute the Stored Procedure within the `SELECT` statement and get one result set
Example:

```
SELECT a, b, c, @var=exec sp_name par1, par2 or
SELECT col1, col2, col3, exec SP_name par1, par2 output
```

Comment: You can't do that with a stored proc, but you can do that with a scalar function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this.  Stored procedures cannot be executed as inline statements.  Unless you are planning to do data manipulation in the stored proc, you really should convert it back to a function.

Or you could always do something like:

```
exec spYourProc @firstINvar, @firstOUTvar output
```

If you have an `OUTPUT` parameter you can use the output param in a `SELECT` query, or whatever query that allows a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your task can be solved useing the `sp_excutesql` as described in the article ["How to specify output parameters when you use the sp_executesql stored procedure in SQL Server"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499/en-us?fr=1)?